# C++ Shared library gives floating point exception when linked with C application

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, grpc, etcd3

**Background:**

A C++ library for `etcd client` having APIs to communicate with `etcd server`, to use this library in C application, we wrote C++ wrappers over this library so that it can be called by C application.

Created a shared library using the below command:

```
g++-7 -ggdb -fPIC -shared -o libetcd_c++.so etcd_client_wrapper.cc etcd_client_txn_wrapper.cc etcd_client.cc etcd_client_txn.cc utils/string.cc pb/*.cc -std=c++1z -I ./pb/etcd -rdynamic -Wl,-call_shared -lglog -lprotobuf -lgrpc++ -lgrpc -Wl,-call_shared -lpthread -ldl -lc
```

placed this library to default library path `/usr/local/lib` and load the library with `sudo ldconfig`.

Now using this `etcd_c++` library APIs, wrote a C code to insert simple key-value to `etcd keyspace`. Compiled using below command:

```
gcc -ggdb -o cwrap sample_wrapper.c -rdynamic -pthread -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-non_shared -lglog -lprotobuf -pthread -lz -lgrpc++ -lprotobuf -lgrpc -lz -lcares -lssl -lcrypto -lunwind -llzma -lgflags -Wl,-call_shared -lpthread -ldl -letcd_c++ -lstdc++
```

The compilation goes fine. But while executing the resulted binary, it gives floating point exception in `grpc++` library.

Questions:

1. What `floating point exception` has to do with the library?
2. We thought it might be an issue with C to C++ transition, but when converted the same C code to C++ with same wrapper API. Gives the `floating point exception`.Now If we replace the wrapper API with direct `grpc++` library API, in the C++ code, it works fine. Is it a linking issue?

Compiling a C++ application:

```
g++-7 -ggdb -o wrap example.cc -std=c++1z -rdynamic -pthread -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-non_shared -lglog -lprotobuf -pthread -lz -lgrpc++ -lprotobuf -lgrpc -lz -lcares -lssl -lcrypto -lunwind -llzma -lgflags -Wl,-call_shared -lpthread -ldl -letcd_c++
```

**EDIT**: Some findings, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grpc/+bug/1797000

Though We are not using `-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions` option, but the issue is somewhat similar to above.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. the exception is probably a divide by zero but could be others too, you'll need to debug it.

Comment: Generally any application that uses a C++ library will need to be linked in the same way a C++ application would get linked by a C++ compiler.

Comment: Possibly the grpc++ wrapper has FP exception handler installed.

Comment: Yes this is a linking issue not a compiler issue. I would be looking at whether or not the ABI is compatible or not, which spoiler alert: it's probably not. Wrappers and compilers are API level, linkers are ABI level.